# how to add iTunes album artwork in Mojave

Tags: macos, itunes, mojave

I do right click > Album Info > Artwork > Add Album Artwork, then I choose a picture (jpg) and then hit "OK" but the artwork isn't added.

Comment: What is the audio format of the tracks you want to add artwork to?

Comment: Do you [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB07t.png) dialogue box  (unless you have previously checked Do not ask me again) when editing the Album info?

Comment: @nohillside wav

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yeah I get that and click "Edit items"

Comment: AFAIK you can‘t add covers to WAV files. You can test this yourself by converting the tracks to MP3 or AAC within iTunes and try to assign a picture there.